# Stuck in the end

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was fighting the ender dragon and died. Upset from dying, I went into creative and used `/setblock` to set an ender portal, so I teleported to the end.

However, when I did that command, I was right next to my bed so when I beat the dragon and went back to the overworld, I spawned on top of the `end_portal` next to my bed and instantly get teleported back into the end. I'm on version 1.12.2 and I've tried the `/execute` command but it tells me `entity 'in' cannot be found`. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Nether portals won't light with normal means while in the End, but that doesn't mean that they cease function completely.

Use `/setblock ~ ~ ~ portal` and you'll be spat out into the Nether through an auto-generated portal. Re-enter the same portal and it'll spit you into the Overworld.

You may want to consider breaking the end portal block once you've returned.

Comment: so i tried that and now im getting the message "the is no such block with name minecraft:nether_portal"

Comment: @ohsoinspire Whoops, in 1.12, I think it's just `minecraft:portal` instead of `minecraft:nether_portal`. Lots of stuff is different in old versions.

Comment: thank you so much. i got out. is there anyway to remove that block now from where i put it to take me to the end

Comment: @ohsoinspire Break it with your Creative Mode fist?

Comment: @ohsoinspire if this helped you, consider clicking the little grey checkmark on the left of the answer to accept it, as it will mark it as accepted and award the answerer reputation.